# JS Quiz: Correct Answer Recognition Issue

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a small JavaScript quiz to practice the language and add a project to my portfolio.

So far, I have successfully implemented randomized questions and choices, a timer, a progress bar and a score counter.

However, I have been unable to have my code recognise the fact when the user is submitting the option that should register as correct and light up green. As a fix, I have tried to put the answers into separate arrays and have the code check the correctness by matching the answer choices with the said answers array. This caused my code to recognize all user input as incorrect.

Please find below a runnable example of my project. You will notice that the choices still light up green or red but they do not take into account the randomized choices thus, incorrectly informing the user of their success. I toned down the CSS and HTML aspects and cut the questions object down to 3 items for the sake of practicality.

I would really appreciate some advice in this regard. Thank you kindly for your time and I'm looking forward to learning about how I can tackle this issue.

```js
const question = document.querySelector('#question');
const choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice-text'));
const progressText = document.querySelector('#progressText');
const scoreText = document.querySelector('#score');
const progressBarFull = document.querySelector('#progressBarFull');
const SCORE_POINTS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 3;

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];

/* Object containing the questions of the quiz game. */
let questions = [{
    question: 'According to Roman mythology, who was the father of Romulus and Remus?',
    choice1: 'A wolf',
    choice2: 'King Numitor',
    choice3: 'Jupiter',
    choice4: 'Mars',
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: 'Which was the first Roman road?',
    choice1: 'Via Egnatia',
    choice2: 'Via Valeria',
    choice3: 'Via Appia',
    choice4: 'Via Flaminia',
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question: 'Which of the following did not defeat Mithridates VI of Pontus?',
    choice1: 'Lucullus',
    choice2: 'Marius',
    choice3: 'Pompey',
    choice4: 'Sulla',
    answer: 2,
  }
]

// Start game by setting default hud values
function startGame() {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuestions = [...questions]; /* Spread operator */
  getNewQuestion()
}

//Randomize question choices
shuffle = array => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

//Get new question and increment the question counter
getNewQuestion = () => {
  if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score);

    return window.location.assign('index.html') /* Take player to end game*/
  }

  questionCounter++;

  const questionsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
  currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionsIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

  //Locate choices
  const answerChoices = [
    currentQuestion.choice1,
    currentQuestion.choice2,
    currentQuestion.choice3,
    currentQuestion.choice4,
  ];

  //Call randomize choices function
  shuffle(answerChoices);

  //Display randomized choices  
  choices.forEach((choice, index) => {
    choice.innerHTML = answerChoices[index];
  });

  availableQuestions.splice(questionsIndex, 1);

  acceptingAnswers = true;
}

//Check answer if correct (Currently can't detect the right answer in randomized choices)
choices.forEach(choice => {
  choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number'];

    let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';

    if (classToApply === 'correct') {
      incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS);
    }

    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

    setTimeout(() => {
      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
      getNewQuestion();
    }, 1000);
  })
})

incrementScore = num => {
  score += num;
  scoreText.innerText = score;
}

startGame()
```

```css
.choice-container {
  color: var(--basic-black);
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--honey-yellow);
  font-size: 3rem;
  min-width: 40rem;
}

.choice-prefix {
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--basic-black);
}

.correct {
  background: green;
}

.incorrect {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
  <div id="hud">
    <div class="hud-item">
      <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
        Question
      </p>
      <div id="progressBar">
        <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hud-item">
      <p class="hud-prefix">
        Score
      </p>
      <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
        0
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 id="question">Sample Question?</h1>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">I.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">II.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">III.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">IV.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be missing some relevant code, for example, `choices` isn't defined

Comment: Thank you, that's my bad. I declared it at the beginning of the full document. "Choices" basically forms an array of HTML elements with the same class. Hence, const "choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice-text'));"

Comment: Can you convert you code into an [MRE] and insert into the question as a runnable snippet? This will make it easier for us to help you, make it clear what isn't working ("I have been experiencing issues" is too vague), and may also help you solve the problem yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, still very new to this. I added a minimal reproducible example and further explanation regarding the issue and my unsuccessful attempts to fix it. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's more room for improvement in the code, but the OP's bug stems from the fact that the `data-number` in the markup is a string and the question object's answer is represented by an int.  Fix either by converting one or the other.

See comment within snippet...

```js
const question = document.querySelector('#question');
const choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice-text'));
const progressText = document.querySelector('#progressText');
const scoreText = document.querySelector('#score');
const progressBarFull = document.querySelector('#progressBarFull');
const SCORE_POINTS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 3;

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];

/* Object containing the questions of the quiz game. */
let questions = [{
    question: 'According to Roman mythology, who was the father of Romulus and Remus?',
    choice1: 'A wolf',
    choice2: 'King Numitor',
    choice3: 'Jupiter',
    choice4: 'Mars',
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: 'Which was the first Roman road?',
    choice1: 'Via Egnatia',
    choice2: 'Via Valeria',
    choice3: 'Via Appia',
    choice4: 'Via Flaminia',
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question: 'Which of the following did not defeat Mithridates VI of Pontus?',
    choice1: 'Lucullus',
    choice2: 'Marius',
    choice3: 'Pompey',
    choice4: 'Sulla',
    answer: 2,
  }
]

// Start game by setting default hud values
function startGame() {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuestions = [...questions]; /* Spread operator */
  getNewQuestion()
}

//Randomize question choices
shuffle = array => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

//Get new question and increment the question counter
getNewQuestion = () => {
  if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score);

    return window.location.assign('index.html') /* Take player to end game*/
  }

  questionCounter++;

  const questionsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
  currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionsIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

  //Locate choices
  const answerChoices = [
    currentQuestion.choice1,
    currentQuestion.choice2,
    currentQuestion.choice3,
    currentQuestion.choice4,
  ];

  //Call randomize choices function
  shuffle(answerChoices);

  //Display randomized choices  
  choices.forEach((choice, index) => {
    choice.innerHTML = answerChoices[index];
  });

  availableQuestions.splice(questionsIndex, 1);

  acceptingAnswers = true;
}

//Check answer if correct (Currently can't detect the right answer in randomized choices)
choices.forEach(choice => {
  choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;

    // HERE: the + sign coerces the string from the markup into an int
    const selectedAnswer = +selectedChoice.dataset['number'];

    let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';

    if (classToApply === 'correct') {
      incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS);
    }

    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

    setTimeout(() => {
      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
      getNewQuestion();
    }, 1000);
  })
})

incrementScore = num => {
  score += num;
  scoreText.innerText = score;
}

startGame()
```

```css
.choice-container {
  color: var(--basic-black);
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--honey-yellow);
  font-size: 3rem;
  min-width: 40rem;
}

.choice-prefix {
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--basic-black);
}

.correct {
  background: green;
}

.incorrect {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
  <div id="hud">
    <div class="hud-item">
      <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
        Question
      </p>
      <div id="progressBar">
        <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hud-item">
      <p class="hud-prefix">
        Score
      </p>
      <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
        0
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 id="question">Sample Question?</h1>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">I.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">II.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">III.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choice-container">
    <p class="choice-prefix">IV.</p>
    <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```